# Would installing RPM cause any problems?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux

I help my brother run a minecraft server for his friends and he needs help updating java. He connects to the server through PuTTY, and is wondering if installing rpm after he has set up the server would affect it in any way?

He also wants to know if updating java while the server is set up would affect it.

Thanks

```
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is the operating info that it shows when you log in to putty.

Comment: Why would it cause any problems?

Comment: I don't know maybe it would affect a file thats critical to the server?

Comment: If you aren't that tech savvy, you shouldn't run your own server. It is not secure, and you end up with questions like this. Installing RPM shouldn't affect the server, but you can't really know (if you do everything correct t shouldn't affect the server). But yeah, backup before doing anything, disable root logging and move ssh away from port 22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't cause any problems, but as ardaozkal has already mentioned always remember to make backups